# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation search doesn't work on 100%

Tags: sharepoint

we have two domains in trust conected throught VPN. I installed SPF2010 in DOMAIN1 and I configured the search by step-by-step which I googled. I created my list but the search from DOMAIN1 has a problem with the search. When I use the search from DOMAIN2 it works on 100%. I have a suspicion to Locale and Regional settings, because the computer from DOMAIN1 using CZECH regional settings and the computer from DOMAIN2 using GERMANY reg.settings. When I search string "ChildSafety" it can be found, but when I search "ChildSafety/FIC" the result can't be found. The same with numbers, when I search string "HDP" it be found in string "FIC/**HDP**/VB" but it didn't be found in string "HDP13". The computer from DOMAIN2 found both strings. Do you have an idea? Thank you

Comment: The collation for content and search databases is Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS

Answer (score 0):

It may be permissions related.  Please ensure that the account you are using to search from Domain1 has the correct permissions in order to see the documents.  Search will only show what you have rights to see.

Comment: I logged on on both sites under the same account with domain admin rights. But in DOMAIN1 I used the same user on comuter and IE and in DOMAIN2 I used domain user on computer but in IE the same user like on DOMAIN1